# Imaginary MySQL fields

Tags: mysql, sql

Can I made up imaginary fields in my MySQL query like

```
Select permission, value
from permissions
```

where there is no `permission` field but I want to assign `true` to it.

Comment: Yep, `SELECT true AS permission, ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 'true' permission, value
FROM   permissions
```

will return a string value
or,

```
SELECT 1 permission, value
FROM   permissions
```

or

```
SELECT true permission, value  -- which is equivalent to 1
FROM   permissions
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to give your imaginary field a name and then you can assign a value to it.
For Example name is `permission`, value is `true`:

```
Select true as permission, ...
from permissions
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT "true" AS permission, value from permissions
```